# Using bootstrap-sass, what would be the hidden-xs equivalent to @include make-sm-column( n )

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-sass

I am very new to sass and i am trying to convert a bootstrap layout to bootstrap-sass so that i can have multiple "brands" use the same code-behind with different layouts.

I've managed to use variations of the following to have two versions with different grid structures:

```
    .someclassname {
       @include make-sm-column(6);
    }
```

is there an equivalent for hidden-xs (perhaps something like @include make-hidden(xs)?

The idea being one site might have a div hidden on mobile but the other site would want the same div visible.

Comment: To my knowledge there is not (feel free to correct me), however Bootstrap 4 has rolled out it's alpha version this past August, it would be a very good timing for you to get a hold of one of their core team members (https://github.com/orgs/twbs/people) and see if such a mixin would be a good idea to add to Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following

```
.someclass {
    @extend .hidden-xs;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.